# How to use child view when iterating over a collection of items in EmberJs

Tags: ember.js

I have a view that has a list of items that I'm iterating over in a template, and rendering that view inside of it as a list item of a . If I use the global name for the template, it works just fine, but I don't want to define that template globally, I want to define it on the current view as a child view. If I reference it outside of the {{#each}} block, it works, but not inside. Is there any way to do this?

```
{{#each items}}
  {{#view Em.App.RecentItemView contentBinding="this"}}
    <a href="#">{{content.Title}}</a>
  {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

The view in context also has an itemView: Em.View.extend({}) on it that I would rather use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would using the `{{#collection}}` helper instead work for you?  Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rharper/PxC7p/) with a working example.

```
{{#collection contentBinding="items" itemViewClass="itemView"}}
     <a href="#">{{content.Title}}</a>
{{/collection}}
```